# Get content related to a user in Strapi

Tags: next.js, strapi, next-auth

I have a collection in Strapi called projects and I want to be able to fetch only the projects belonging to the currently logged in user. I'm using Next.js with NextAuth on the frontend and I'm currently filtering the results using:

`/api/projects?filters[user][id][$eq]=${session.id}`

This works fine except the endpoint still allows a user to fetch projects for all users if accessed directly. I'm thinking a better approach would be to setup a custom API endpoint in Strapi which would be something like `/api/projects/:user`. Is this the best way to acheive this? I've managed to setup a custom endpoint in Strapi using the CLI but I'm not sure what logic needs to go in the controller. Would modifiying an exisiting endpoint be better?

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up extending my controller. In `src/api/controllers/project.js` I made the following changes:

```js
"use strict";

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::project.project", {

  async find(ctx) {
    const user = ctx.state.user;
    ctx.query.filters = {
      ...(ctx.query.filters || {}),
      user: user.id,
    };
    return super.find(ctx);
  },
});
```

Then simply call the `/api/projects` endpoint.

Answer based on this guide [Limit access of Strapi users to their own entries](https://dev.to/paratron/limit-access-of-strapi-users-to-their-own-entries-298l).

Answer (score 2):

Custom endpoint create is good idea. I had same problem. Once  i created custom endpoint then i got data with entitiyservice. It's work. Below image is my code.

./scr/api/[collection]/controllers/[collection].js

```
'use strict';


const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::user-profile.user-profile', ({ strapi }) => ({
async me(ctx) {
    try {
        const user = ctx.state.user;
        const datas = await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::user-profile.user-profile", {
            filters: {
                user: {
                    id: user.id
                }
            }
        })
        return datas;
    } catch (err) {
        ctx.body = err;
    }
}
}));
```

If you will use all endpoints in collection like (create,update,delete,find,findone). You must override the all endpoints . Example is the below.

```
'use strict';


 const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::education.education', ({ strapi }) => ({
async create(ctx) {
    try {
        const user = ctx.state.user;
        ctx.request.body.data.users_permissions_user = user.id
        const datas = await strapi.entityService.create("api::education.education", {
            ...ctx.request.body
        })
        return datas;
    } catch (err) {
        ctx.body = err;
    }
},
async update(ctx) {
    try {
        const user = ctx.state.user;
        ctx.request.body.data.users_permissions_user = user.id
        const { id } = ctx.params;

        const experienceData = await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::education.education", {
            filters: {
                users_permissions_user: {
                    id: user.id
                },
                id: id
            }
        });

        if (experienceData.length === 0) {
            return {
                data: null,
                error: {
                    message: ''
                }
            }
        }

        const datas = await strapi.entityService.update("api::education.education", id, {
            ...ctx.request.body
        })
        return datas;
    } catch (err) {
        ctx.body = err;
    }
},
async delete(ctx) {
    try {
        const user = ctx.state.user;
        const { id } = ctx.params;

        const experienceData = await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::education.education", {
            filters: {
                users_permissions_user: {
                    id: user.id
                },
                id: id
            }
        });

        if (experienceData.length === 0) {
            return {
                data: null,
                error: {
                    message: ''
                }
            }
        }

        const datas = await strapi.entityService.delete("api::education.education", id)
        return datas;
    } catch (err) {
        ctx.body = err;
    }
},
async findOne(ctx) {
    try {
        const user = ctx.state.user;
        const { id } = ctx.params;

        const experienceData = await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::education.education", {
            filters: {
                users_permissions_user: {
                    id: user.id
                },
                id: id
            }
        });

        if (experienceData.length === 0) {
            return {
                data: null,
                error: {
                    message: ''
                }
            }
        }

        const datas = await strapi.entityService.findOne("api::education.education", id)
        return datas;
    } catch (err) {
        ctx.body = err;
    }
},
async find(ctx) {
    try {
        const user = ctx.state.user;
        const datas = await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::education.education", {
            filters: {
                users_permissions_user: {
                    id: user.id
                }
            }
        })
        return datas;
    } catch (err) {
        ctx.body = err;
    }
},
}));
```

No extra endpoints and no extra codes.
Strapi v4

Answer (score 1):

Yes, creating separate endpoint for this task would be great.

Instead of `/api/projects/:user` using this type of route, use `/api/projects` as you can get current logged in users details from ctx.state.user

No, Instead of modifying your existing controller create new controller and use that controller to satisfy your needs.